# ¿Como soluciono este error en el "if"? me dice que no tengo la variable asignada

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error lo marca en el segundo if, no se por que me marca el error si ya la asigne en int. Lo que estoy programando es que al insertar un numero de dos digitos me diga si un digito es multiplo del otro

```
 int num, dig1, dig2;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero de 2 digitos");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num >= 10 && num <= 99)
        {
            dig1 = num / 10;
            dig2 = num % 10;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El numero no es de 2 digitos");
        }
            if (dig1 % dig2 == 0 || dig2 % dig1 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uno de los digitos es multiplo del otro");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ninguno de los digitos es multiplo del otro");
            }
            
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues el código, en lugar de subir una imagen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es declarar sin inicializar:

```
int numero;
```

Si intentas leer la variable ahora tendrás un error. Pero puedes definirla luego:

```
número = 12;
```

Esto es declarar e inicializar:

```
int numero = 0;
```

Supongamos que el primer condicional no se cumple. El código generará un error cuando intente verificar el segundo condicional porque las variables no están definidas.

Puedes optar por inicializar esas variables:

```
int num, dig1 = 0, dig2 = 0;
```

Puedes dejarlas sin definir y detener el programa si la primera condición no se cumple con un `return`.

O puedes decantarte por poner el segundo condicional dentro del primero. Entonces solo si las variables se definen, sigues con el procesamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo es un problema las variable, te recomiendo que muevas el if que validad los múltiplos dentro del primer if, te quedaría así:

```
if(num > 10 && num <= 99)
{
    //Tu código asignación de valores a las variables dig1 y dig2;
    if (dig1 % dig2 == 0 || dig2 % dig1 == 0)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Uno de los digitos es multiplo del otro");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Ninguno de los digitos es multiplo del otro");
    }
 }
```

Le puedes asignar un valor a las variables (dig1 y dig2), pero de igual forma es mejor reestructurar las validaciones, de esta manera queda mejor.